# Concatenating strings at n position from 2 lists

Tags: python

I'm trying to concatenate strings at every n'th position from 2 lists. But I can't seem to get it to work

Input:

```
['57', '60', '55',..., '56']

['g', 'b', 'r',..., 'b']
```

Output:

```
['57g', '60b', '55r',..., '56b']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Utilizing the full arsenal of built-ins, you can do the following, using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
l1 = ['57', '60', '55', '56']
l2 = ['g', 'b', 'r', 'b']

list(map(''.join, zip(l1, l2)))
# ['57g', '60b', '55r', '56b']
```

which is a rough equivalent of the following [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[''.join(pair) for pair in zip(l1, l2)]
# ['57g', '60b', '55r', '56b']
```

which, in turn, could just use simple string concatenation:

```
[x1 + x2 for x1, x2 in zip(l1, l2)]
# ['57g', '60b', '55r', '56b']
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is the key function in all of them as it does the *parallel* 
 pair(triplet, quadruple, ...)-wise iteration of multiple iterables.

Comment: Since we're joining pairs of strings, I think the last version is the best. And it's probably the fastest, too.

Comment: @PM2Ring I agree, for the case at hand, it is also the most intuitive. However, it is not quite as flexible as the others if there is an unknown number of lists.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this problem is:

```
L1=['57', '60', '55',.......'56']
L2=['g', 'b', 'r',......'b']
list=[]
for i in range(length of your array):
     list.append(L1[i]+L2[i])
print(list)
```

list.append() method is used to insert the values to the list. Suppose you want to insert 4 in list then:

```
list=[1,2,3]
list.append(4)
print(list)
```

output:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

I hope you understand